# Tapping a UITableView cell is creating a new cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a table, and when I click on a cell, I want to get access to that cell so I can change some properties of that cell, but for some reason it's creating a new cell each time. I can tell this because `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` is getting called every time I tap on a cell.

Here's my code for creating the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AccountsCell";

    NSLog(@"AccountsTableViewController : cellForRow");

    AccountsTableViewCell *cell = (AccountsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (nil == cell)
    {

        cell = [[AccountsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    [cell setCurrentAccount:[self.accounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;

}
```

And for selecting a cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    AccountsTableViewCell *cell = (AccountsTableViewCell *)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is creating a new cell each time rather than giving me a reference to the cell that was tapped?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: it probably has something to do with this line of code: cell = [[AccountsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  where you create a new cell if the tableview didn't dequeue one. Why would your table view not be able to dequeue a cell?

Comment: Make sure you register your table view for your re-use identifier, it's likely every call to cellForRowAtIndexPath is always creating a new cell, because the identifier isn't registered to the tableview

Comment: To register it programatically, use `[tableView registerClass:[AccountsTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're essentially creating a new `AccountsTableViewCell` by re-rerunning the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method with the `tableView` and `indexPath` as parameters.

Instead of writing:

```
AccountsTableViewCell *cell = (AccountsTableViewCell *)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

try

```
AccountsTableViewCell *cell = (AccountsTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to get the `tableView`'s current cell at `indexPath`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this, it's been driving me nuts and you probably just saved my job.

Comment: @SeanT Haha no problem. Glad you won't lose your job. ;)